# Turn Js Variable into Meta data

Tags: javascript, metadata, google-tag-manager, meta

in the head section I have a js:

```
var product = {
                ProductID: '97087',
                Thema: '18',
                CategoryID: '49',
                Region1: ['21'],
                Region2: ['35'],
                Region3: [],
                Price: '22,00',
                Brand: 'Brand',
            };
```

Is there a way to turn the ProductID into a Meta tag like

```
<meta name="brand" content="97087">
```

Comment: do you have a backend? (php, python ...)

Comment: nope - just tagmanager

Comment: Do you want this so a search engine can read the meta data? the answers will most likely use javascript to append the newly created tags to the head of the document. A search engine most likely won't run JS, so the tags will not be created.

Comment: No - i want to set the meta from the js so i can extract ist an add it to interactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by looping though the keys of the product object and appending it with the associated value to the `<head>`. The code below will result in:

```
<meta name="ProductID" content="97087">
<meta name="Thema" content="18">
<meta name="CategoryID" content="49">
<meta name="Region1" content="21">
<meta name="Region2" content="35">
<meta name="Region3" content="">
<meta name="Price" content="22,00">
<meta name="Brand" content="Brand">
```

```js
var product = {
                ProductID: '97087',
                Thema: '18',
                CategoryID: '49',
                Region1: ['21'],
                Region2: ['35'],
                Region3: [],
                Price: '22,00',
                Brand: 'Brand',
            };
            
var metaTags = Object.keys(product).map(function(key) {
  return '<meta name="' + key + '" content="' + product[key] + '">';
}).join('');

var headElem = document.querySelector('head');
headElem.innerHTML += metaTags;


console.log(headElem.querySelectorAll('meta'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ive got errors with that script:
'''Fehler in Zeile 2, Zeichen 42: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.'''

'''Fehler in Zeile 3, Zeichen 10: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: template literal.'''

Answer (score 0):

Save this snippet to test it

Just create the meta tag with JS and append it to the head of your document

Run it and right click to inspect the head tag to see the meta is created

```js
   

var product = {
                ProductID: '97087',
                Thema: '18',
                CategoryID: '49',
                Region1: ['21'],
                Region2: ['35'],
                Region3: [],
                Price: '22,00',
                Brand: 'Brand',
            };


//<meta name="brand" content="97087">

var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.setAttribute('name',product.Brand);
meta.setAttribute('content',product.ProductID);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

[image]

Comment: Check it again ! its created added an image to show it